# Remove last part of string in column if strings match pattern in pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to remove the end part of strings if the strings matches a specified pattern.

These are the two string formats I'm working with:

```
ColA
2-OX-1011054-LWJ04-HT-01
2-VH-0611052-LWJ04-HT-001
```

I'd like to remove the `-01` and `-001` from both.

I know I could write something that removes everything after the last `-` however there's a lot of other strings in that column of different patterns, which will get messed up if I do that.

So I'd only like to remove the last part if the string exactly matches the pattern.

I've used something like this before, however I'm not 100% sure how it works, but I'd guess it could be refactored to my purpose:

```
report['ColA'] = report['ColA'].str.replace(r'(?<=^\w{2}-\d{5}-\d{3})(-\d+)', '', regex=True)
```

EDIT: Should specify that not all the end numbers are `01` or `001`. It could be any number from `000` to `999`

Answer (score 1):

```py
report['ColA'] = report['ColA'].str.replace(r'(?<=^\d{1}-\w{2}-\d{7}-\w{3}\d{2}-\w{2})(-\d+)', '', regex=True)
```

Comment: You can omit the capture group from `(-\d+)` as you already use the lookbehind assertion.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
report['ColA'] = report['ColA'].str.replace(r'-0{1,2}1', '', regex=True)
```

It only works for `-01` and `-001`. Is it what you wanted?
EDIT
If it's any number, this should work

```
report['ColA'] = report['ColA'].str.replace(r'-\d+$', '', regex=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

> *"There's a lot of other strings in that column of different patterns"*

You can use:

```
report['ColA'] = report['ColA'].str.replace(r'^(\d+-[A-Z]{2}-\d{7}-[A-Z]{3}\d\d-[A-Z]{2})-\d{1,3}$', r'\1', regex=True)
```

The pattern `^(\d+-[A-Z]{2}-\d{7}-[A-Z]{3}\d\d-[A-Z]{2})-\d{1,3}$` means:

- `^` - Start-line anchor;
- `(` - Open 1st capture group;

  - `\d+` - 1+ Digits (remove the '+' if you are certain this will always just be a single digit);
  - `-[A-Z]{2}` - A literal hyphen followed by two uppercase alpha-chars;
  - `-\d{7}` - An hyphen followed by 7 digits;
  - `-[A-Z]{3}\d\d` - A literal hyphen followed by three uppercase alpha-chars and two digits;
  - `-[A-Z]{2}` - A literal hyphen followed by two uppercase alpha-chars;
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group;
- `-\d{1,3}` - An hyphen followed by one to three digits;
- `$` - End-line anchor.

We use the content of the 1st capture group to replace the whole (matched) string with. This way you have validated that you only replace those digits where needed.